# Azure Service Bus - Message: ConnectionsQuotaExceeded

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, quota

We received the following `ConnectionsQuotaExceeded` message from `Azure Service Bus`:

## **Exception**

> EventName="MessageEvent" Message="One or more unknown errors occurred communicating with the Service Bus.
>   Exception Type: QuotaExceededException
>   Exception Depth: 0
>   Message: ConnectionsQuotaExceeded for namespace production.

## **Stack Trace**

> Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.RetryAcceptMessageSessionAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult r)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.EndAcceptMessageSession(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory 1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func 2 endFunction, Action 1 endAction, Task 1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Platform.ServiceBus.Utilities.ResilientQueueClient.<>c__DisplayClass23.<b__22>d__25.MoveNext() in d:\vsoagents\18\s\Cloud.ServiceBus.Utilities\ResilientQueueClient.cs:line 0
>
> Exception Type: FaultException`1
>   Exception Depth: 1
>   Message: ConnectionsQuotaExceeded for namespace production.
>   Stack Trace: 
>   Server stack trace: 
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)

## **Problem**

The quotas are outlined in [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/) document. The exception appears to refer to this `Connection Quota`:

**Number of concurrent connections on a namespace.**

- Subsequent requests for additional connections will be rejected and an exception will be received by the calling code.
- REST operations do not count towards concurrent TCP connections.
- NetMessaging: 1,000
- AMQP: 5,000

My problem is we are unable to isolate our exact usage of this quota , likely the number of AMQP connections.

It seems these thresholds are invisible to users until the limitation is reached causing an exception like this. From a capacity planning point of view this make it difficult to understand when scaling will be required on any related resource.

Looking at the Azure portal UI performance for Service Bus the following metrics are available:

- Incoming Messages
- Internal Service Errors
- Length
- Server Busy Errors
- Size
- Successful Requests
- Other Errors
- Total Requests

Importantly no connections, no AMQP threads, infact none of the quota thresholds detailed in the article [ref](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/).

## **Question**

Is there a method via the Azure API or another Azure UI to examine and alert on the quotas documented in the Service Bus Quotas article or at the very least the number of `AMQP` connections to a service bus namespace ?

Comment: Hey Scott, don't know the answer but have you tried Azure Service Bus EventHub ? Eventhub can ingest millions of messages per second. Could be a solution for you ?

Comment: Hello Thomas. Thank you for the post. We have an R&D team on the case :) I agree with your comment that EventHub mitigates this issue but redesigning our platform archtiture to support EventHubs will take a few months. Thanks for the post. Scott.

Comment: Yeah sure, It takes time and time is money :-)

Comment: Other things that could do the trick: batch your messages before sending them to the queue or implement a custom retry strategy to handle `ConnectionsQuotaExceeded` as transient fault. see the documentation here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680901(v=pandp.50).aspx) and how to configure it on the service bus client.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938849/implementing-exponential-retry-policy-for-servicebustransienterrordetectionstrat/).

Comment: To Thomas' point, is this because you have too many devices, or too many connections per device? Another option, would be to break things out by namespace, but unfortunately, you cannot forward messages between namespaces, so there would be some manual work involved.